# How to see the trend of "the percentage of organic search in all acquisition channels" in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

It's very easy to see how much of your traffic is from Search, how much is from Social and how much is from Direct and so on, like this:

[image]

We can tell that 11.03% is from Organic Search. And after setting the date duration to another range afterwards, the number became 15.55%. That is growing.

But I can't see the percentage trend for this. Is it possible to see it directly rather than dumping out all data and put everyday's number in a new Excel or Google Spreadsheet to figure out its trends?

What I expected is something like this:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way of seeing the *percentage* over time, but you can get the absolute numbers over time.

Like other "compare stats over time", Google Analytics hides it under "motion charts".

1. Choose the date range for which you are interested
2. Navigate to "Acquisition" -> "All Traffic" -> "Channels"
3. Click on "motion charts" (icon with three black circles top right of the graph)
4. Change the metric of the graph from "% new sessions" to "sessions" (sideways drop down to the left of the graph)
5. Change the graph to a line chart (small gray line chart in a tab over the graph as opposed to the black line chart icon next to the motion charts icon)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question you have there, I browsed Analytics quite some time to give you the answer below.

The truth is that it's not possible to do it the way you want, because the Metric Sessions is not possible to be sorted on the graph as percentage of total.

The best thing you can do is to open the Channels and isolate the Organic Traffic and change the metric to % of new visits, this gives you an idea if your new visitors coming from Search Engines are increasing.

Other then this, Excel is your best friend.

Comment: Just wondering, is there any channel that I can send this as a feature request to Google.

Comment: I don't think so, as far as I know you can start with the General Support here https://support.google.com/analytics/#topic=3544906 and the forums here https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/analytics